# Чтение файла в массив

Tags: java

Как считать текст с файла `.txt` а потом данные с него передать в массив?

Застрял на этом:

```
package Project_2402;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Programm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("input.txt"))
        {
           //читаем посимвольно
            int c;
            while((c = reader.read())!=-1){

                System.out.print((char)c);
            } 
        }

        catch(IOException ex){

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Stream<String> lineStream = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("input.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset()).lines()) {
        final String[] lines = lineStream.toArray(String[] :: new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lines));             
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```